# How to pass value from a control on Silverlight (mainPage.xaml) to control on asp.net(default.aspx ) page

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a scenario where I want to pass data from controls on the silverlight page to controls on the asp.net page.I tried to search on it and found example of javascript but that is not helpful for me. I read about the WCF also but since I am new this world of silverlight I not able to produce result from it. So please if anyone have any solution please help me and also if a source code example is there then it will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use javascript to setup a function for the silverlight to call.  The javascript can then receive the value and set the control accordingly.  This is a good example of silverlight - javascript integration:

http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/08/tip-of-the-day-15-communicating-between-javascript-amp-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your trying to do,

If you are trying to pull data from a database the best is a Webservice.

If your just trying to call a server side method on ASP.NET you will have to use javascript and update panels to trigger post back without the page doing a refresh, or javascript doing ajax calls (POST,GET) to your ASP.NET App.

Please describe better what you are trying to do.